# Agregar clase según el valor de width con JS

Tags: javascript, progressbar, style, width

Estoy tratando de agregar la clase bg-success o bg-warning a un progress bar según su valor de style="width:20%"

Actualmente extraido los datos en una página PHP y los pinto con un echo:

```
            echo "<tr>
              <td>".$result -> nombre."</td>
              <td>".$result -> materia."</td>
              <td>".$result -> asignatura."</td>
              <td>

              <div class='container-fluid'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-md-12'> 
                    <div class='progress'>
                      <div id = 'barra' class='barra progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated' role='progressbar' style='width: ".$result -> calificacion."%' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='10' aria-valuemax='100'>
                        ".$result -> calificacion."%   
                      </div>
                    </div>
                        <span class='sr-only'>".$result -> calificacion."%</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              </td>
            </tr>";
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, me pinta el progress bar de color azul, pero quiero cambiar el color conforme al valor que estoy tratando de obtener con un JS al final de la página, ejemplo:

```
           <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
               function cargaColor() {
           
                  var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName('barra');
                  var valor = document.getElementById('barra').offsetWidth;
                  for(var i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++)
                  if ($valor >= 100) {
                    $elemento[i].className += ' bg-success';
                  } else {
                    $elemento[i].className += ' bg-warning';
                  }

                  }
                  window.onload = cargaColor;
                </script>
```

Si yo ejecuto el script solo con -$elemento[i].className += ' bg-success'- me cambia el color de la barra a verde, pero cuando ya intento hacer función IF y traerme el valor actual de style=width, ya no funciona, estuve buscando diferentes forma de obtener el valor de style=width para poder jugar con ello y adicionar la clase pero sigue sin funcionar, alguna idea?...

De antemano gracias por sus respuestas.

Saludos comunidad.

Comment: En js no es necesario poner el simbolo $ antes del nombre para llamar a una variable if (valor >= 100) { es suficiente.

Comment: Tienes razón, sin embargo aún así no logro obtener el valor de width para poder cambiar el color de la barra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente estás concatenando las clases; supongamos que en la primera vez asignas `bg-success` y en la siguiente `bg-warning`, el elemento quedará con `class="barra bg-success bg-warning"`, entonces el navegador aplicará la que encuentre primero o la que sea [más específica](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) en la hoja de estilos.

En lugar de asignar la clase como cadena, usa la propiedad [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) que tiene métodos para agregar (add) y quitar (remove), entre algunos otros.

Otro error que tienes es que declaras las variables `elemento` y `valor`, pero dentro del ciclo tratas de acceder a ellas anteponiendo un `$` que, aparte de no ser necesario en Javascript, no lo usaste para declarar las variables.

Sugerencias:

- Crea tus variables usando `let` en lugar de `var`, para que puedan ser usadas solo en el bloque o función donde las declaras.
- Cuando usas `window.onload` solo puedes asignar un evento y, además, la ejecución podría retrasarse, dependiendo de lo que pase con otros scripts, eventos, etc. En su lugar, usa `.addEventListener` y, mejor aún, con el evento `DOMContentLoaded` asignado al documento, para que se ejecute en cuanto el navegador termine de interpretar el contenido de la página.

```js
function cargaColor() {
    let elemento = document.getElementsByClassName('barra');
    let valor = document.getElementById('barra').offsetWidth;
    for(let i = 0; i < elemento.length; i++) {
        if (valor >= 100) {
            // Agregar clase
            elemento[i].classList.add('bg-success');
        } else {
            // Eliminar clase
            elemento[i].classList.remove('bg-success');
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cargaColor);

// Probando
document.querySelector('#ampliar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('#barra').style.width = '100px';
    cargaColor();
});
document.querySelector('#reducir').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('#barra').style.width = '50px';
    cargaColor();
});
```

```css
.barra {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:5px;
    background:#f90;
    margin:2px;
}
.barra.bg-success {
    background:#0c0;
}
#barra {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<span class="barra"></span>
<span class="barra"></span>
<span class="barra"></span>
<div id="barra"></div>
<button id="ampliar">Ampliar barra</button>
<button id="reducir">Reducir barra</button>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias!, finalmente opté por dejar solo datos duros.